# XSD schema for Mandatory or Optional fields

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

If an element in an xsd is defined as below :

```
<element name="test" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string" />
```

Does that mean that :
1. The tag  can be completely removed the XML and still there won't be any validation errors
OR
2. The tag  can be empty/blank without any value

Which is the best way/practice to define mandatory/optional elements.

Thanks
WN

Answer (score 3):

Both.

The element `test` may be omitted.

The element `test` may be present just once with any string content, including empty string:

```
<test/>
```

Best practice? Depends on what you want to express.

`minOccurs="0"` is about structure.

If you want to express a contraint on the data level, you can do something like:

```
<xs:element name="test" minOccurs="0" type="tns:nonEmptyString"/>

<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So think about if your constraint is about structure (is the item present or not) or data (may the item have an empty value or not) and apply accordingly. There are also nillables but I won't even start about them.